# Changing the default text of SmartGWT listgrid

Tags: smartgwt

How can I change the text which the smartgwt listgrid show by default when there is no records to display. For e.g. now it displays a text "No items to show." I want to be able to change this text. Another reason for changing is I have RTL language for my application and want to be able to enter the text in that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ListGrid` source:

```
/**
 * The string to display in the body of a listGrid with an empty data array, if showEmptyMessage is true.
 *
 * @param emptyMessage emptyMessage Default value is "No items to show."
 * @see com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid#setShowEmptyMessage
 * @see com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid#setEmptyMessageStyle
 * @see <a href="http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_empty_grid" target="examples">Empty grid Example</a>
 */
public void setEmptyMessage(String emptyMessage) {
    setAttribute("emptyMessage", emptyMessage, true);
}
```